# Postgresql multiple joins in single query where foreign key of a join doesn't exist in all tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

Is it possible to have two joins in a single query, where the second join is a connection between table_2 and table_3 (no key references in table_1)?

```
table_1

id | column_a



table_2

id | table_1_id | table_3_id | column_b



table_3

id | column_c
```

Existing Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_2 WHERE table_1.id id = ? and WHERE column_a = ?
```

Gives me the info I want from table_1 and table_2, but table_2's info will have just the table_3_id column.

**In the same query, I'd like to join table_3 to get its data based on table_2.table_3_id**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word - yes. You can just add more `join` clauses:

```
SELECT           * 
FROM             table_1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.table_2_id = table_2.id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_3 ON table_2.table_3_id = table_3.id
WHERE            table_1.id = ? AND column_a = ?
```

Comment: thanks! i tried this initially but had a typo for one of my table names and thought it might not have been possible

Answer (score 2):

You `where` clause is turning the `right outer join` into an `inner join`.  I'm not a fan of right joins in general.  I think the semantics of a left join are simpler.

So, you should write this as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM table_1 t1 JOIN
     table_2 t2
     ON t2.table1.id = t1.id JOIN
     table_3 t3
     ON t2.table3.id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = ? AND column_a = ?;
```

Notes:

- You should not use `outer join` and then undo them in the `where` clause.
- You should list the columns you want explicitly.
- You should qualify *all* column references in a multi-table query.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.